# How to partition a data frame into multiple data frames by a value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R:

```
ID  col1
1   10
2   40
3   5
4   33
5   37
6   2
7   102
8   11
9   76
```

I'd like to get a set of data frames from this by partitioning where the rule for the partitioning is that: split where `col1<10` (and omit rows where `col1<10`, albeit this could be done later, of course). So the requested output:

df1:

```
ID  col1
1   10
2   40
```

df2:

```
ID  col1
1   33
2   37
```

df3:

```
ID  col1
1   102
2   11
3   76
```

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: I don't think this question is actually a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question want's to split on a factor, here there is a flexible condition `col1 < 10`.

Comment: This code does the trick:
`df <- data.frame(ID = 1:11, col1 = c(10, 40, 5, 33, 37, 2, 5, 102, 11, 76,9));
  split_points <- c(which(df$col1 < 10), nrow(df)+1);
  last_p <- 1;
  indices <- lapply(split_points, function(p){
    if(last_p >= p-1){
      tmp <- numeric(0)
    }else{
      tmp <- seq(last_p, p-1)
    }
    last_p <<- p+1;
    tmp
  });
  
  lapply(indices, function(idx){
    df[idx, ,drop=FALSE]
  })`

Answer (score 1):

This creates a list whose elements are the individual data frames:

```
grp <- cumsum(df$col1 < 10)
by(df, grp, subset, col1 >= 10)
```

giving:

```
grp: 0
  ID col1
1  1   10
2  2   40
------------------------------------------------------------ 
grp: 1
  ID col1
4  4   33
5  5   37
------------------------------------------------------------ 
grp: 2
  ID col1
7  7  102
8  8   11
9  9   76
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "ID  col1
1   10
2   40
3   5
4   33
5   37
6   2
7   102
8   11
9   76"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```